# rowsPerPage not working with dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo

Currently i am getting 100 Records from my Servlet .

I want to display only 20 Records per page , i am using dojox.grid.DataGrid , but still its displaying all the 100 Records 
Please   help .

```
<body class=" claro ">
        <span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="store1" url="http://localhost:8080/Game/servlet/Hi"></span>

<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="store1" rowsPerPage="20" rowSelector="20px"
   style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="150px" field="name">Namer3</th>
            <th width="150px" field="dept">Deptr3</th>
                    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start using a QueryReadStore, and change your servlet to respect the start and count parameters that are part of the post.  This will allow the grid to fetch the rows 1-20, then 21-40 when the user scrolls down, and so forth.

If you're looking to tell the grid to render only 20 rows at a time and wait for a scroll event for the others, that should already be handled.  I would suggest you double check your grid.  Initially 20 rows should be rendered with values, and the later ones should just have "..." inside all the values until scrolled into view.